# PHP: List of days between two dates

Tags: php, date

Is there an easy way to get a list of days between two dates in PHP?

I would like to have something like this in the end:

(pseudocode)

```
date1 = 29/08/2013
date2 = 03/09/2013

resultArray = functionReturnDates(date1, date2);
```

and the resulting array would contain:

```
resultArray[0] = 29/08/2013
resultArray[1] = 30/08/2013
resultArray[2] = 31/08/2013
resultArray[3] = 01/09/2013
resultArray[4] = 02/09/2013
resultArray[5] = 03/09/2013
```

for example.

Comment: How about: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php ?

Comment: I have tried taking apart the dates and seperate them into date1Day, date1Month, date1Year, date2Day etc... I started by subtracting the different years, months and days to count how many days there were. Then starting from date1 just adding dates. I run into a problem because of months with 30/31/28/29 days...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
$date1 = '29/08/2013';
$date2 = '03/09/2013';

function returnDates($fromdate, $todate) {
    $fromdate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $fromdate);
    $todate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $todate);
    return new \DatePeriod(
        $fromdate,
        new \DateInterval('P1D'),
        $todate->modify('+1 day')
    );
}

$datePeriod = returnDates($date1, $date2);
foreach($datePeriod as $date) {
    echo $date->format('d/m/Y'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.
Since I'm quite new to PHP if you have another second could you tell me what the backslashes mean?

Comment: It's a good idea to learn about DateTime objects: powerful and flexible, timezone and daylight savings aware; they and their related objects (DatePeriod and DateInterval) can really make working with dates simple

Comment: @user2018084 see [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: The backslashes are a [namespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) reference, indicating classes in the global scope.... if you're not using namespaces, then you don't need to worry about them: they're not needed, but they won't do any harm

Answer (score 7):

```
function DatePeriod_start_end($begin,$end){

        $begin = new DateTime($begin);

        $end = new DateTime($end.' +1 day');

        $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);

        foreach($daterange as $date){
            $dates[] = $date->format("Y-m-d");
        }
        return $dates;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

dunno if this is at all practical, but it works pretty straight-forward

```
$end = '2013-08-29';
$start = '2013-08-25';
$datediff = strtotime($end) - strtotime($start);
$datediff = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
for($i = 0; $i < $datediff + 1; $i++){
    echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start . ' + ' . $i . 'day')) . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function daysBetween($start, $end)
   $dates = array();
   while($start <= $end)
   {
       array_push(
           $dates,
           date(
            'dS M Y',
            $start
           )
       );
       $start += 86400;
   }
   return $dates;
}

$start    = strtotime('2009-10-20');
$end    = strtotime('2009-10-25'); 
var_dump(daysBetween($start,$end));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$datearray = array();
   $date = $date1;
   $days = ceil(abs($date2 - $date1) / 86400) + 1;//no of days

   for($i = 1;$i <= $days; $i++){

     array_push($datearray,$date);
     $date = $date+86400;

   }
     foreach($datearray as $days){
      echo date('Y-m-d, $days);
      }
```