# Storing a range of dates in one row in database or in seperate table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to make a car booking system using a jquery datepicker. I have the date picker, I have dates in a database(manually inserted in WAMP SERVER phpMyAdmin) that highlight those dates as pre-booked dates (Cursor disabled in css on mouse over) so you can't book those ones.

I'm at the point of assembling all my parts but have become stuck on the last bit of how to store the dates. It seems from what I've read, that storing a bunch of dates in one row is a no no (plus I haven't managed to do it).

1. So, should I store a start and end date for each client on the one DB table row and generate the in between dates when the page/datepicker loads?
2. If this approach how do I get and then join each row (many clients) of dates together?
3. Or should I generate the in between dates and then store all the dates in a separate table with the client id when the datepicker selects start & end?

Could someone help with the correct approach and php code to get me there. I already have the mysqli connection etc.

My DB columns at present are `start_date` & `end_date` in table`dates_from_to`. My datepicker uses this format `2021-04-15` and the array needed looks like this `'2021-04-15','2021-04-16','2021-04-17'` to highlight the dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about a month I have the date-picker working, storing all dates in DB on their own row.

> It picks a start date & end date from two datepickers.

> Creates/produces all the dates in between then inserts all those separate dates into the database each date in it's own row in PHP.

> Then redirects to same page & highlights all DB dates & disables them so no one can select already booked dates.

I have copied different bits of code from this site and manipulated it a little & at present I'm very happy with the hybrid outcome.

This is running on a WAMP server.

Below is my code to help other amateurs like me.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost:3308";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "datepicker_test_outputs";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$sql = "SELECT date FROM insert_datesarray";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$for_JS_date = null;

// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    
    $php_array_dates = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row["date"]));
    
        $for_JS_date .= "'".$php_array_dates."'".",";
        
            $correct_date_format = substr($for_JS_date, 0, -1);
            }


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){

$start_date = $_POST["from"];
$end_date = $_POST["to"];

$dateentry = array();

// populate $dateentry array with dates
while (strtotime($start_date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    $dateentry[] =  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date));
    $start_date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($start_date)));
} // end while

// loop through $dateentry and insert each date into database
foreach($dateentry as $entry) {

    $my_inserted_dates =("INSERT INTO insert_datesarray 
        (date)  VALUES('{$entry}')")
        or die(mysqli_error());
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$my_inserted_dates);

if($result == false)
{
    echo "<script>alert('BOOKING IS NOT SUCCESS - PLEASE CONTACT ADMINISTRATOR');      </script>";
}
else
{
   /* Header location to refresh the page & load booked dates */
   header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

}

} die;
// end foreach
}
}

?> 
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery UI DatePicker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
    .ui-highlight .ui-state-default{
        background: red !important;
        border-color: red !important;
        color: white !important;
            cursor:not-allowed !important;

    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var dates = [<?php echo $correct_date_format;?>];       
    /*var dates = ['2021-04-05','2021-04-15','2021-04-25','2021-04-30'];*/
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('input[id=from]').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',/*CN  Changes date format. Remove if required  CN*/
            changeMonth : true,
            changeYear : true,
            minDate: 0 ,/*Mindate disables dates before todays date*/
            beforeShowDay : function(date){
                var y = date.getFullYear().toString(); // get full year
                var m = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // get month.
                var d = date.getDate().toString(); // get Day
                if(m.length == 1){ m = '0' + m; } // append zero(0) if single digit
                if(d.length == 1){ d = '0' + d; } // append zero(0) if single digit
                var currDate = y+'-'+m+'-'+d;
                if(dates.indexOf(currDate) >= 0){
                    return [true, "ui-highlight", 'Date Already Booked'];   
                }else{
                    return [true];
                }                   
            }
        });
    })
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">       
    var dates = [<?php echo $correct_date_format;?>];       
    /*var dates = ['2021-04-05','2021-04-15','2021-04-25','2021-04-30'];*/
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('input[id=to]').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',/*CN  Changes date format. Remove if required  CN*/
            changeMonth : true,
            changeYear : true,
            minDate: 0 ,/*Mindate disables dates before todays date*/
            beforeShowDay : function(date){
                var y = date.getFullYear().toString(); // get full year
                var m = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // get month.
                var d = date.getDate().toString(); // get Day
                if(m.length == 1){ m = '0' + m; } // append zero(0) if single digit
                if(d.length == 1){ d = '0' + d; } // append zero(0) if single digit
                var currDate = y+'-'+m+'-'+d;
                if(dates.indexOf(currDate) >= 0){
                    return [true, "ui-highlight", 'Date Already Booked'];   
                }else{
                    return [true];
                }                   
            }
        });
    })
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="dateFrom"></p>
<p id="dateTo"></p>
<form action="" name="form1" method="post">
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from"onchange="getFromDate()">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to"onchange="getToDate()">
<input name="book" type="submit" value="Book">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: You have an error. [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) needs one argument. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have a 1:n relation between clients/customers and bookings. So yes you should store them in separate tables according to [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) rules.

Assume you have a table clients (primary key client_id) and bookings, which replaces your dates_from_to table (with foreign key client_id) you can do the following JOIN:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM clients
  JOIN bookings 
 USING (client_id) 
 WHERE booking_date = '2021-04-05'
```

For the next part I take the example array. Here is example code to insert one row for every day:

```
$dates = ['2021-04-15','2021-04-16','2021-04-17'];

// $pdo contains a connected DB instance
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO bookings (client_id, booking_date) VALUES (?, ?)');

foreach ($dates as $day) {
    $stmt->execute([1, $day]);
}
```

As an alternative you could use first and last day of the period and store everything in one row by replacing `booking_date` column by `start_date` and `end_date`.

Here is the version with mysqli and start/end date (from [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");

$mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO bookings (client_id, start_date, end_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');

// iss means (i)nteger, (s)tring and (s)tring parameter
$stmt->bind_param('iss', 1, '2021-04-15', '2021-04-17'); 
$stmt->execute();
```

Hope this keeps you going.

Comment: Thanks @jumper85, I'll need every **booking** date so it highlights the already booked dates in the date picker, so you're saying to generate the dates and insert them into the bookings table? If the start date is `2021-04-05` & end is `2021-04-15` there would be 11 days/dates how do I go about coding that & inserting into DB bookings table?

Comment: ah now I understand, so you want one booking entry for every day, no matter if it is a booking by one person over several days? alternative would be to have one record with start and end date.

Comment: I adjusted the answer a bit, let me know if I assumed in the right direction ;-)

Comment: Thanks @jumper85. I think I like `start_date` & `end_date` but I'm getting nowhere fast. I found this code here <https://stackoverflow.com/a/18513846/4975737> by @MarkBaker but can't get it into a variable or converted into something the jquery datepicker likes. Whether it's for the datepicker or storing it in separate rows I'm having a big problem solving this.

Comment: you mentioned your date picker expects `2021-04-05` format, so just use format for this `$date->format('Y-m-d');` and to get `$date` you can simply create new object from your value in DB `$date = new DateTime($dbDate);`

Comment: I think I'm asking the wrong questions & feel I'm wasting your time. I'm using mysqli. How do I insert the dates as separate rows from here <stackoverflow.com/a/18513846/4975737>

Comment: extended my answer with alternative and mysqli, don't think that you really need the linked SO entry because if I understand correctly, then you already get the dates from your date picker in the correct format and you get start and end date, no need to calculate days in between

Comment: Thanks @jumper85 for being patient, that puts the start and end date in which doesn't really help me as, if it were only one booking it would work fine, but there will multiple different clients booking cars so I will have multiple different pairs of start & end dates. So my thought was to get all the dates between start and end each time a booking happens and insert them all into DB with the client ID, there will be the other clients dates inserted at booking time. I can then just grab **all** the dates at once & highlight the dates in the datepicker.

Comment: Part 2, I ran out of comment space. Else do you know how to concatenate the result of each pair of start & end dates of each client stored in DB which would be as the page loads? So client 1s total dates concatenate to client 2s dates and so on. So this will be on the pairs of start & end being the only part stored.

Comment: don't know if I understand the requirement of part 2 ;) because I don't know exactly how all of your stuff works, maybe it would be easier to store every day of a booking in a single row, then you have to mix part 1 & 2 of my answer and the SO page you mentioned to get the dates between start and end. You can concat values in MySQL with `GROUP_CONCAT` combined with `GROUP BY`.